# Spring Boot Security without Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'd like to secure all pages in "/static/secure" in Spring Boot utilizing Spring Security, but I do not wish to utilize a view.

I have created a login form, with method="POST", and have setup Java-Based configuration class to go to /static/secure/main.html on success.

I wish I could approach from a specific problem standpoint, unfortunately everything I can find for guidance on how to authenticate uses Thymeleaf, or a view. I really just want it to navigate to /static/secure/main.html upon successful login, not call a view. Does anyone know how to configure Spring Boot to just go to a regular HTML page upon authentication?

I am attempting to just use Spring Security to handle login, then the rest of the app will be Angular once we're in, hitting REST API endpoints as needed - so I don't really want the "view" concept, nor Thymeleaf in the mix.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you,
Dan

Comment: Please add a `java` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successful authentication redirects to the page the user initially tried to open. So as long as you secured your `/static/secure` folder, accessing `/static/secure/main.html` will trigger authentication and then automatically redirect to that page on success.

You configuration overall will look something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
}
```

(Given you serve your Angular pages from `/static/...` URLs and the pages themselves go from `/src/webapp/static` folder in your Maven project.)

In your Spring Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/secure/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        // ...
}
```